# is it possible to change a Char into a String with a loop/if

Tags: vb.net

I got a knew problem which should be the last one from my bonus exercise. At first let's explain the rules, I have a word which is shuffle. I want my user to find this word and he has a determined number of tries.

Now I want to let the user know which char from his input (txtBox.Text) was right and which one aren't. So I tried to create a method which is able to Color a char in green **If** the char is correctly positionned **else** in red. I ask my teacher and it seems to be a hard thing to do, I tried to find the solution he gave me with richBox but it's way too hard right now, i'm struggling way to much.

So ! I think of something way simpler, or at least i thought it was simpler,  I get the user input in a String and I do a loop around it, every time the correct word and the input char doesn't match I replaced it by a dot.

It doesen't work either if I try to put an index to my :

```cpp
If word(i) IsNot proposition(j) Then
```

I'm facing an out of bound and if I try without it, it consider my string as an array of 1 and add to my listbox a single dot.

Here's my code :

```cpp
    Public Sub charRight&Wrong()
        Dim proposition() As String = {txtInput.Text} //get the proposition from the user
        Dim dot As Char = "."
        Dim word() As String = {theWord} //theWord represent the right answer

        For i = 0 To theWord.Length - 1
            For j = 0 To proposition.Length - 1
                If word(i) IsNot proposition(j) Then
                    proposition(j) = dot
                End If
            Next
        Next

        lboAttempts.Items.AddRange(proposition.ToArray)
    End Sub
```

I don't really know where I'm wrong I hope you can point it out. Thanks again.

Comment: replace `IsNot` with `<>`

Comment: You probably want `word` and `proposition` to be `Char()` instead of `String()`, which can be done using `ToArray`.

Comment: Thanks for both of your answer. I have replaced my isNot, is good to know we can do this this. So I did tried to replace as you suggest for word and proposition and add it to my listbox but I have the same problem, either addRange(proposition.toArray) doesn't work or Add(proposition) print me "Char[]Array". I can't find anything on internet about this question ...